# Android Espresso functional tests with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, functional-testing, android-espresso

I have three activities in my app

1. A login activity
2. A main activity
3. A detail activity

I want to use espresso to test a sequence of events: click the login button on the login activity, which opens the main activity, and then click a list item in main activity, which opens detail activity, and then click another button in the detail activity. I started by creating this simple test, to get a reference to the listview:

```
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

    public LoginActivityTest() {
        super(LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        getActivity();
    }

    public void testSequence() throws Exception {
        // Login
        onView(withId(R.id.button_log_in)).perform(click());

        // Check if MainActivity is loaded
        onView(withId(R.id.container)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

        // Check if Fragment is loaded
        onView(withId(R.id.list)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

On the **mainActivity** `onCreate()` method I load a fragment like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, mListFragment)
                .commit();
```

The **ListFragment** fragment has a list (`R.id.list`), but still the test fails with a `NoMatchingViewException`:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.tests.android.development:id/list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: If you are still looking for help with this, please show the complete code of `onCreate()` that is related to this question. In particular, show the declaration and intialization for `mListFragment`. Also show the XML layout for the `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 1):

A note from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html#onView(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.view.View%3E)) for `onView`:

> Note: the view has to be part of the view hierarchy. This may not be
>   the case if it is rendered as part of an AdapterView (e.g. ListView).
>   If this is the case, use Espresso.onData to load the view first.

To use `onData` to load the view, you need to check for instances of whatever your adapter is in the ListView. In other words, if your listview uses a Cursor adapter, you can try this:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Cursor.class)))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

It is important to note that the above will only pass if your listview contains at least one item. It is a good idea to have one test where an item exists, and one test where an item does not.

For more information on how to check for data that does exist, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Matching_data_using_onData_and_a_custom_ViewMatcher).

For more information on how to check for data that does not exist in an adapter, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples#Asserting_that_a_data_item_is_not_in_an_adapter).

Comment: No amount of data matching will put the List into the hierarchy, which the error is about. Your guidance is valuable, but only **after** the error at hand is resolved, for which you gave no information.

Comment: Tip: `onData(instanceOf(Cursor.class))` should achieve the same data query. `allOf` doesn't make sense for a single matcher and `is` is redundant by definition. However, `is` may make sense, if it makes the code read more English: here it doesn't, because of `allOf`.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (Espresso 2.2.2) this exception is always appended with a `View Hierarchy:` clause that lists all the views available to match. Stroll through that and check if you can find your list.

As an alternative: check out `android-sdk\tools\uiautomatorviewer.bat` (or .sh) which takes a snapshot from the current screen and hierarchy. Put a breakpoint on your list matching line and check with the viewer if the list is there. If you find the list, there may be a timing issue in the test. Maybe it didn't wait enough, check out more about `IdlingResource`s.